# Angular JS unable to call factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

My code below

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller('starterController', function ($scope, starterFactory)
{
    $scope.buttonClick = function () {
        debugger;
        alert("buttonClicked");
        $scope.name = starterFactory.getName();

    }
})
.factory('starterFactory',function()
{
    debugger;
    var var1 = "akshay";
    return {
        getName :function()
        {
            debugger;
            return var1;
        }
    };
})
```

I am new to the angular js.No matter what i do i am not able to call getName function because injector failed.what is that i am doing it wrong? Or is there any better way to do same things?

Comment: Provide the error details

Comment: I apologies for mistake it was auto generated code problem...when i use double quote for starterController and starterFactory problem solved and i am able to call the function. i can not believe how stupid it was.Thank u :)

Comment: yes...those errors can be misleading ...a syntax error can show misleading messages. You should just delete this question...it won't be of any value in the future